# Dockerfile; docker build volumes: changes to volume via ADD or COPY are not discarded

Tags: build, docker, volume, dockerfile

I have a dockerfile with something like:

```
VOLUME /tmp/space
ADD local/directory/ /tmp/space/
RUN cp /tmp/space/somescript.sh /opt/real/space/
```

After the container is built and I get an interactive shell I notice that the /tmp/space still contains the data from local/directory.

If I add a `RUN rm -rf /tmp/space/*` to the end of the dockerfile and get shell access.  The data is still there in /tmp/space/.

As a result, I'm left making a running container using the same volume and then committing the changed container to an updated image.

Is there a method to, during the build, have a temporarily loaded volume that doesn't bloat the resulting image?

The goal is to use source files and scripts to perform some actions during a build.  The layers of docker end up recording a duplicate of the `COPY/ADD` step with the `RUN` step.  So it would be better to `COPY` the data into a space that isn't recorded as a layer then as a single `RUN` step `cp stuff && execute scripts` to save on space.

Comment: What I've ended up doing is using COPY for the whole local folder and maintaining a dockerignore file to skip over the files I don't want in the resulting image.  Not ideal but it does end up saving me about 200MB of space.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do here:
VOLUME /tmp/space - this declares a mount point and maps /tmp/space on your container to a directory on the host

ADD /local/directory /tmp/space - I think you are attempting to copy a local directory from your container to your mounted volume

RUN cp /tmp/space/* /opt/real/space/ - Are you trying to copy from your volume to your host?

After adding a VOLUME directive in a dockerfile, what happens is that the folder in the container **/tmp/space** is mapped to a folder on the host, say **/hosttmp/hostspace**. You can find out what this is on the host by running the command -

```
$ docker inspect -f {{.Volumes}} <your_container_name>
```

In order to prevent corruption of data in **/hosttmp/hostspace**, once a VOLUME is declared in the dockerfile, you cannot play around with the contents.

I would recommend reading this article as it explains the rather confusing docker volume concept

http://container-solutions.com/understanding-volumes-docker/

Comment: I edited the question to try and make it clearer what I'm trying to do.
The problem I'm encountering is that VOLUME isn't mapping to a local folder for ADD and COPY commands in the dockerfile (running docker 1.9.1 at time of writing).

Comment: You need to move the VOLUME command to the end of your docker file. This is after you have done any ADD or COPY commands to that folder. The last step should be mounting it i.e VOLUME

Comment: But what I'm trying to do is use files during the build process and have them NOT end up in the resulting image.  I want the VOLUME before the ADD or COPY so those files are not in the resulting image.

Comment: I finally understand what you want to do. You want to use some files during the build process and then delete them after. To do this, you don't need VOLUME. You can just ADD or COPY the files, and then before you start your container, you can RUN rm -rf /tmp/space and this should work.

Comment: Unfortunately that bloats the resulting image.  I've opened a bug with docker.  If you add a single file it is not added to the image as expected, but if you add a file via a wild card or as part of a whole directory it is permanently added to the image.